# different rendering output for Symfony 2.8.x/Twig when on mobile/desktop browsers

Tags: jquery, html, symfony, twig

This is my Twig template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <label for="self_service_form_type_0">{{ form_widget(form.type[0], { "attr":{"class":"radio"}}) }}<span>Student ID number</span></label>
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

When viewed on a desktop browser, this is the rendered output which is what I expected looking at my Twig template.

```
<label for="self_service_form_type_0">
   <input id="self_service_form_type_0" class="radio" type="radio" value="student" name="self_service_form[type]"><span>Student ID number</span>
</label>
```

When viewed on a mobile browser or a desktop browser with a mobile user-agent, this is rendered output:

```
<label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off" for="self_service_form_type_0">
   <span>Student ID number</span>
</label>
<input id="self_service_form_type_0" class="radio" type="radio" value="student" name="self_service_form[type]">
```

As you can see, the input tag is inside the label tag on desktop browsers while on mobile, it's outside. **This is causing problems with my mobile jQuery code.**

I thought by rendering the fields individually (as explained in the Symfony manual), I wouldn't be expecting this kind of issue.

Any ideas on how to make the mobile output the same as desktop? thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this has nothing to do with `twig` as `twig` nor `symfony` knows about the device being used.

Comment: Sometimes the browser change the HTML if it thinks it is not wellfomated. For example in Firefox Desktop you can see the source code with right click show source code. But if you read the HTML code in the console, it is diplayed with some auto corretions.

Are you sure your mobile HTML hasn't be edited by the mobile browser ? If yes you can try to desable JQuery and compare the HTML again.

Comment: I've tested using the same desktop browser (Firefox) but I changed the user-agent to fool the server to render mobile template instead. I'll try using the desktop HTML source instead of the Twig templating and see what happens. thanks